# Custom validation attribute's ValidationContext is missing a field

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm working in MVC 5. I'm writing a form for users to submit claims to an internal application, and I need to validate the user's claim amount against their current balance when they create a claim. It rejects if the amount is greater than the balance, say $10 vs. $5, and asks them to zero out their balance instead.

I felt it would be best to have the balance be a (non-editable) property, `CurrentBalance`, on the viewmodel with a custom validation attribute comparing the two values. I render it as a readonly field on the form. When the user picks which program they are submitting to, like their HRA, an ajax request fills in their current balance per which program they selected.

The trouble is that when the viewmodel instance is passed as part of the `ValidationContext` to my attribute, `CurrentBalance` *always* appears as zero. Here's a snip while debugging: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0Dkt.png

So no matter what the balance is, validation fails without exception.

I've tried making `CurrentBalance` an ordinary, non-readonly field on the view and setting the value myself before submitting. I've also tried setting the value in my controller before rendering the view. In either case, it's still zero, as in the image above.

My custom attribute is as follows:

```cs
public class ClaimAmountAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var claim = (ClaimCreateViewModel)validationContext.ObjectInstance;
        var amount = (decimal)value;

        if (claim.CurrentBalance - amount < 0)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(GetErrorMessage());
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }

    public string GetErrorMessage() => "Amount must be less than balance; please zero out balance instead.";
}
```

Here are the relevant parts of my view—though again, it didn't seem to make a difference whether the readonly attribute was there or not:

```
@model ClaimCreateViewModel

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CurrentBalance, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CurrentBalance, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" } })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Amount, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Amount, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Amount, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Finally, here's a snippet from the viewmodel:

```cs
public class ClaimCreateViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public int TransactionID { get; set; }
    // ...

    [Required]
    [ClaimAmount] //my custom attribute
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Balance")]
    public decimal CurrentBalance { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

Seemingly nothing I do produces the value of `CurrentBalance` in the `ValidationContext`. Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is embarrassing. It turns out that **the `[Bind]` attribute on my POST action was missing `CurrentBalance`**. Validation occurs before the action, but that doesn't matter; `[Bind]` is acting before then, to prevent overposting. I've updated that action and it works now:

```cs
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "TransactionID,Amount,CurrentBalance")] ClaimCreateViewModel claim)
{ 
    // ...
}
```